# Getting ID from tagged user

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Hey I was wondering if I can check if someone is being tagged and if they are get the user ID of the person tagged and use it as reporting

```
let [cmd, user, proof, reason] = msg.content.split(' ');
        let reporting = user //user being reported (usually tagged)
        let reported = msg.author.tag
        let reportedID = msg.author.id

let embedReply = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor("PURPLE")
        .setTitle("Ready to send?")
        .setDescription("Please check if this is correct:")
        .addField("Your name:", `${reported} (${reportedID})`)
        .addField("You are reporting:", `${reporting} (${reporting.id})`)
        .addField("With the proof:", proof)
        .addField("With the reason:", reason)
        .setFooter("Please check this report so you know what you're sending.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>*I am the author of the npm package shown in this answer. The sole reason for including it is for its ease of use and application.*</sup>

You could use my [`discord-mentions`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-mentions) package to extract the desired mention out of the string. See the package page for more details and specific usage.

Example:

```js
// Require the package.
const getMention = require('discord-mentions'); // Don't forget to install.

// Extract any mentions from 'reporting.'
let mention = getMention(reporting, message.guild);

// If there is a mention, assign the member to 'reporting.' Otherwise, search for them by tag.
if (mention) reporting = mention.member;
else reporting = message.guild.members.find(m => m.user.tag === reporting);

// If the mention was not of a (valid) member, or none could be found, return an error.
if (!reporting) {
  return message.channel.send(':x: Unknown user. Use a mention or their tag.')
    .catch(console.error);
}

// 'reporting' is now a GuildMember. Use 'reporting.user.id' for their ID.
```