# TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined with DM

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I wanted my bot DM the user before they got banned but it just errors and I think there might be more errors in my code which I can't see

```
'ban': (msg) => {

        let [cmd, userBan, proof, ...reason] = msg.content.split(' ');

        let mention = getMention(userBan, msg.guild)
        if (!mention) {msg.reply("Please mention a user to ban.")}



        if(!msg.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) {
            return msg.reply(embedNoPermBan)
        }

        if(!msg.author.id == "296750415964274689") {
            if(!msg.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) {
                return msg.reply(embedNoPermBan)
            }
        }

        if(!userBan) {return msg.channel.send(embedNoUser)}

        if(!proof) {return msg.channel.send(embedNoProof)}

        if(!reason) {return msg.channel.send(embedNoReason)}



        userBan.member.send(embedUser).then(user => {
            userBan.ban(reason)
        })

        msg.channel.send(embedBanned)
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are giving `userBan` the value resulting from

```
let [cmd, userBan, proof, ...reason] = msg.content.split(' ');
```

I would say that `userBan` is a string. But then, you are doing:

```
userBan.member.send(embedUser)
```

Since `userBan` is a string, `userBan.member` has `undefined` value. And you are trying to call the `send` method from `userBan.member`. Hence you get the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Comment: See the example code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56760250/getting-id-from-tagged-user/56761595#56761595) to extract a GuildMember out of a string.